# Type checking on google apps script platform

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, typechecking

Is there a way to check againts built-in types in google apps script? 
I don't know how to access contructors of built-in types. So I can't use instaceof operator.

For example Profile (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_analytics_v3_schema_profile )

```
function getReportDataForProfile(profile) {
if (profile instanceof Profile) // Profile is undefined...
...
}
```

Also what is a litle confusing: When I get an instance of Profile (in variable profile)

```
profile.constructor // is undefined
```

Comment: Why do you need the Profile constructor? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if I need constructor. I want to test if profile (function parameter) is istance of Profile. 
Of course this is only example. I want to do this for any object.

While "duck typing" is always a possibility, I hope there is some simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this won't be a necessarily clean solution, but it will be functional nonetheless.

If it is a Profile object, then `profile.getKind()` will return `analytics#profile`. However, if the `.getKind()` method is not defined for that object, it will throw an error. So it looks like you'll have to do 2 checks.

```
if (typeof profile.getKind != "function") {
  if (profile.getKind() == "analytics#profile") {
    //profile is a Profile!
  } else {
    //profile is some other kind of object
    //use getKind() to find out what it is!
  }
} else {
  //profile doesn't have a getKind method
  //need a different way of determining what it is
}
```

Comment: This is actually nice solution! Unfortunetly the getKind method is not used consistently trough google API. It seems that getKind is available only for "Google APIs Services". But not for "Default Services" like Spreadsheet or Gmail.

Comment: This is the only way that I found to accurately identify a Profile object. I understand that it does not identify any other object.

Answer (score 10):

After observing the output of `Logger.log()` it is clear that for most built-in Google Apps objects the output of the `toString()` method is the Class name:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
if (typeof sheet == 'object')
{
    Logger.log(  String(sheet)     ) // 'Sheet'
    Logger.log(  ''+sheet          ) // 'Sheet'
    Logger.log(  sheet.toString()  ) // 'Sheet'
    Logger.log(  sheet             ) // 'Sheet' (the Logger object automatically calls toString() for objects)
}
```

So any of the above can be used to test the *type* of the object (except the last one example that obviously works only with the `Logger`)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases "in" can be used to verify the object by its properties:

```
function CheckType( fileOrFolder ) {
  if ( "getName" in fileOrFolder )
    if ( "getFiles" in fileOrFolder ) return "folder" ;
    else if ( "getBlob" in fileOrFolder)  return "file" ;
  return "neither file nor folder" ;
}

function ShowType( Obj ) {
  let Type = CheckType( Obj ) ;
  console.log( "%s is a %s", "getName" in Obj ? Obj.getName() : Obj.toString(), Type ) ;
}

ShowType( DriveApp.getFiles().next() )   ;
ShowType( DriveApp.getFolders().next() ) ;
ShowType( DriveApp ) ;
```